# convert two dimensional string array to two dimensional int array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, int, nullreferenceexception

I'm trying to convert a two dimensional string array to a two dimensional int array:

```
int[][] inner = new int[4][];

string[][] arr = new string[4][]
{
    new string[] {"11"},
    new string[] {"12"},
    new string[] {"21"},
    new string[] {"22"}
};

for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    string name = string.Join(".", arr[i]);
    for (int j = 0; j < name.Length; j++)
    {
        inner[i][j] = Convert.ToInt32(name.Substring(j,1));
    }
}
```

But I'm getting the following exception:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

at:

```
inner[i][j] = Convert.ToInt32(name.Substring(j,1));
```

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Comment: `inner[0]` is null. That will cause the NRE you're seeing.

Comment: Put a break point on that line and see what is null, simple.

Comment: you have created a two dimensional array, but only populated one dimension. The arrays iterated over with the j variable are all empty so you end up calling null.Substring which causes the exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the declaration of your "inner" variable to

```
int[,] inner = new int[4,2];
```